# Mesh moves when applying rig

Tags: rigging, armature

My Name is Cem, I'm a beginner at Blender and I have a question.

I've made an arm in blender, and I've placed the bones. But, when I apply the armature to my mesh (ctrl+p, with automatic weights), the arm moves a little bit on the X-axis and my mesh becomes bit messed up.

This is my arm before parenting, and how I want the rig,
[image: Arm before parenting]

and this is my arm after parenting.
[image: arm after parenting]

By the way, I had the arm rigged first without the nails and that worked as it should. I added the nails later, I made them in a new object and later connected the arm object and the nails object with ctrl+J, I believe.

How can I rig the arm without it becoming weird like this? Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: maybe try to: deparent the arm object / apply the scale and rotation of both the arm and armature / make sure that the armature is in rest pose (Alt R, Alt S, Alt G in Pose mode). If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much

Comment: so did it fix your porblem?

Comment: yeah, it did! sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

- Deparent the arm object
- Apply the scale and rotation of both the arm and armature
- Make sure that the armature is in rest pose (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> in *Pose* mode).